# How comes is ROW_NUMBER() faster than GROUP BY (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, group-by, row-number

I have a query which produces about 11 million rows.

When I try to GROUP BY on the result it takes a very long time (>20min) to run.

On the other side, when I use ROW_NUMBER() which gives an equivalent result, it runs **much** faster (~6sec).

For example:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM [some JOIN which produces 11million results]
GROUP BY a,b,c,d
```

How comes it is so much faster?

Comment: Did you look at the explain plan results for each method?

Comment: are you retrieving all rows when you use the row_number query? I suspect you aren't; most database GUIs (such as Toad, SQL Developer, etc) only fetch a certain number of rows at a time (500 rows is the default in Toad). If you don't specifically request all rows, then you're only getting the first chunk of rows.

Comment: you seem to be missing an aggreate clause  (ie count/sum/min/max)  from your group by, so its not clear what you are comparing row_number() to.